# Simple syntax to print out Nim address

Tags: nim-lang

How to print out Nim address
just like in C:

```
 int array[] = { 7, 8, 9 };
 printf(" %p ", (void *)&array);
```

? the try:

```
 var
   arr = newSeq[array[2,int]](2)
   refVar = addr arr

 echo refVar
```

gave:

```
Error: type mismatch: got <ptr seq[array[0..1, int]]>
but expected one of: 
proc echo(x: varargs[typed, `$`])
  first type mismatch at position: 1
  required type for x: varargs[typed]
  but expression 'refVar' is of type: ptr seq[array[0..1, int]
```

Please help out !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `repr` to get a string representation of a value that also contains the memory address:

```
var
  arr = newSeq[array[2,int]](2)
  refVar = addr arr

echo arr.repr  # 0x7f5c2fcbd050@[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
echo refVar.repr  # ptr 0x564bd37d7528 --> 0x7f5c2fcbd050@[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the memory address alone (not what else repr gives you), the simplest way is:

```
echo cast[int](arr.addr).toHex
```